# IEEE 1394/Firewire sniffers?

Tags: packet-capture, packet-sniffers, sniffing, firewire

Does anybody know any software (for win7 or winXP) that will allow me to capture or simply see data transferred between Firewire device and Application.

I wish to see data streams between my (ASIO) audio interface that works on firewire and my recording/mixing software.

Thank you

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have exact same problem and no idea how to deal with it :( Special software is enough or do I need a piece of hardware too? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes-you need a firewire bus protocol analyzer. Look on ebay for CATC (Lecroy) FireInspector. There are a few listed recently, some reasonably priced, some not.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Bushound (http://perisoft.net/bushound/) which allows for bus I/O analyzing on a pure software level.